# How to list databases in terminal in PostgresSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, terminal, command, psql

I'm experienced with MySQL, but I've just started to work with Postgres - from the terminal, how can I see the list of existing Postgres databases using the `psql` command?

I checked the documentation and I've seen this issue brought up here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql, where the accepted solution is to simply type `psql \l`, and that makes sense to me... however, when I try this, I get the error

`psql: FATAL:  database "l" does not exist`

but I am logged in to Postgres - if I type `psql DATABASE_NAME`, no problem, I get into the database... this was an issue for me recently because I couldn't remember the name of the database that I wanted to work on.  I went into another table (the name of which I did remember), then used the `\l` command to see my databases and connected to the DB I needed, but I'd much rather just be able to see a list without having to first connect to a database.  How can I do that?

Comment: database `postgres` always exists.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful to know.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thanks to @Michał Sznurawa for pointing me in the right direction - from the Mac terminal, using `psql -l`, rather than `psql \l` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This lists all databases:

```sql
SELECT datname FROM pg_database;
```

These list all databases in detail:

```
\list
```

```
\l
```

These list all databases in more detail:

```
\list+
```

```
\l+
```